# Underlying reasons of clusters

Tags: clustering

In order to find underlying patters in my mixed data set, I'm executing a dissimilarity daisy test (gower distance for mixed data). After I've got the results, I do apply a PAM for finding clusters, and this gives me a clear view of the clusters.

In my case, I've got 10 observations (companies) and they contain 17 parameters. Now I'm wondering if there is a test or a way of clustering, that allows me to cluster the parameters instead of the companies. In other words, I would like to find the underlying reasons why some companies are clustered together.

Thank you in advance!